# Retrieve data from heterogeneous std::list

Tags: c++, list

In the below code I am simply trying to experiment with a Heterogeneous std::list where I have stored three Derived class object in a list of type Base*. When retrieving data from the list I am having some problem. How do I do this? The below code works because all the three classes are identical in definition. So the compiler somehow manages to give me my expected output.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class Base;
typedef std::list<Base*> any_list;

class Base{};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    std::string s;
    Derived1():s("D1"){}
};
class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    std::string s;
    Derived2():s("D2"){}
};
class Derived3 : public Base
{
public:
    std::string s;
    Derived3():s("D3"){}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    any_list l;
    l.push_back(new Derived1);
    l.push_back(new Derived2);
    l.push_back(new Derived3);

    for(any_list::iterator itr=l.begin();itr!=l.end();++itr)
        std::cout<<((Derived1*)*itr)->s;
}
```

Please note the o/p is -

> D1
>   D2 
>   D3

Now this doesn't work if I add one extra member in any of the classes ( That's expected and correct). So how should I typecast the data and retrieve it from a heterogeneous list?
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way might be to define Base like so:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual const std::string& getData() = 0;
}
```

And then have your various derived classes implement `getData()` as appropriate. That way, your output loop could just be:

```
for (Base* b : l) {
    cout << b->getData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would redefine `Base` to have a virtual method to output the information:

```
class Base {
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &os, const Base &b) {
        b.print(os);
        return os;
    }
    virtual void print (std::ostream &os) const = 0;
public:
    virtual ~Base () {}
};
```

You are then forced to implement a `print` method in each derived class. Your print loop would look like:

```
    for (any_list::iterator itr=l.begin();itr!= l.end();++itr)
        std::cout << **itr;
```

Your list should avoid managing bare pointers, since you put yourself at risk of leaking memory. You can use a smart pointer instead:

```
typedef std::list< std::unique_ptr<Base> > any_list;
```

Since `unique_ptr` requires explicit construction from the pointer, your code that populates the list needs to be updated.

```
    l.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived1));
    l.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived2));
    l.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived3));
```

Comment: A "fancier" version of the solution I outlined above can be found [here](http://ideone.com/YXFq64).

Answer (score 0):

Your cast `(Derived1*)*itr` is equivalent to a `static_cast` which states:

> If the prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 `B`” points to a `B` that is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type `D`. Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined.

So you have undefined behaviour because you are casting pointers that point at `Derived2` and `Derived3` objects to a `Derived1*`.

The proper way to achieve this is to have `std::string s;` defined in `Base` and give it a constructor that takes a `std::string` argument. Then you can make the constructors of `Derived1` to `Derived3` call this constructor with the appropriate string argument.

If you add any extra members to one of the `Derived` classes, you won't be able to access them through the polymorphic `Base*`. However, trying to do that is a sign of bad design. You should only be treating the objects that a `Base*` points at as though they were `Base` objects. That is, `Base` describes the interface for those objects.

If you *really need to* do something that is derived class specific to an object pointed to a `Base*`, you can use a `dynamic_cast`:

```
if (Derived1* p = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(*itr)) {
  // This condition will only be true if the object pointed to by `*itr` really is a Derived1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class Base;
typedef std::list<Base*> any_list;

class Base{
public:
    virtual ~Base(){}
    virtual std::string getData()=0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    std::string s;
    Derived1():s("D1"){}
    std::string getData()
    {
        return s;
    }
};
class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    std::string s;
    Derived2():s("D2"){}
    std::string getData()
    {
        return s;
    }
};
class Derived3 : public Base
{
public:
    std::string s;
    Derived3():s("D3"){}
    std::string getData()
    {
        return s;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    any_list l;
    l.push_back(new Derived1);
    l.push_back(new Derived2);
    l.push_back(new Derived3);

    for(any_list::iterator itr=l.begin();itr!=l.end();++itr)
        std::cout<<((Base*)*itr)->getData()<<std::endl;
}
```

Thanks for the help. Confusion is clear and the problem is solved. By d way what is -

> typedef std::list< std::unique_ptr > any_list;

I didn't find anything called `unique_ptr` in `std::` namespace. :(

Comment: To get unique_ptr, you need to include `<memory>`, and compile your code with a C++11 compiler (with GCC, you use the `-std=c++11` command line option).