# unique_ptr member, private copy constructor versus move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, g++-4.7

Given a base class for multiple derived class, the goal was to create a wrapper class that allowed an STL container to see objects with the base interface, event though different derived classes may actually be added to the container. (See [Retrieve data from heterogeneous std::list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15796341/315052)).

After some tinkering, I came up with a new derived class that was a wrapper around a `unique_ptr` to the base class. However, the move constructor has me confused.

```
class Base {
    friend class BaseWrapper;
    virtual Base * clone () const = 0;
public:
    virtual ~Base () {}
    //... public interface
};

class Derived : public Base {
    //... specific members for derived class
    Base * clone () const { return new Derived(*this); }
public:
    //... implement public interface
};

class BaseWrapper : public Base {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr_;
    Base * clone () const { return ptr_->clone(); }
public:
    BaseWrapper (const Base &b) : ptr_(b.clone()) {}
    //... implement public interface by forwarding to ptr_
};

typedef std::list<BaseWrapper> BaseList;

int main () {
    BaseList l;
    l.push_back(Derived());
}
```

[This does not compile with g++ 4.7.2](http://ideone.com/IFjkuo).

Now, in order to use `BaseWrapper`, I can implement a public move constructor like this:

```
    BaseWrapper (BaseWrapper &&bw) { ptr_.swap(bw.ptr_); }
```

[And this works fine](http://ideone.com/w9FW9W). But, if I make it private, [it will not compile](http://ideone.com/uHmkTP).

However, I found that instead of the above, [I can instead define a private "copy" constructor](http://ideone.com/uZe9hm) (making it public also works, of course):

```
    BaseWrapper (BaseWrapper &bw) { ptr_.swap(bw.ptr_); }
```

Could someone tell me if this was supposed to work, and why or why not? If it is supposed to work, why can I not make the move constructor private?

You can follow [this link](http://ideone.com/ZPeEoi) to the toy program illustrating the above in a more complete way.

Comment: I'm not sure why in your example the compiler is trying to use the implicitly deleted copy ctor when it should use the move ctor. [On gcc 4.8 for example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2cW7iN$0) it compiles, but [clang 3.2 it doesn't](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2fUtBE$0).

Comment: @JesseGood: Thanks. I am finding that the trickiness of using `unique_ptr` correctly is outweighing its usefulness, and I will probably be recommending `shared_ptr` over `unique_ptr` because of it.

Comment: Note that removing `virtual ~Base () {}` allows it to [compile on g++4.7.2](http://ideone.com/Un5EbY) which prevents implicit declaration of the move ctor and there is a note `When the move constructor is not implicitly declared or explicitly supplied, expressions that
otherwise would have invoked the move constructor may instead invoke a copy constructor`. I'm still not sure who is right though.

Comment: @JesseGood: So, I am supposed to define a template constructor to allow each derived class to install their own deleter?

Comment: I'm not an expert on `unique_ptr`, but I think you are supposed to define the proper constructors in `Base` (move, copy and default) since you have a user-defined dtor. (I think the idea is, since you have a user-defined dtor, most likely the default move and copy ctor will not do the right thing).

Comment: @JesseGood: If true, it's another argument against using `unique_ptr` in my book. The virtual destructor does nothing, so it should not impact rule of three or rule of five, or whatever...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[removed the erroneous diagnostic]

That actually compiles on gcc 4.8. It seems like gcc 4.7 takes `BaseWrapper (const Base &)` as a copy constructor(which is actually not), and implicitly deletes the move constructor(which would be expected behaviour if it were indeed a copy constructor).

Comment: You need to provide some way of moving the `unique_ptr` when pushing it into the list. That's either a move or a copy constructor(taking a reference, rather than a const-reference). That's why you need to define one, otherwise the `unique_ptr` member can't be moved into the list. As for why the move constructor can't be private, I've answered that above.

Comment: That's because your copy constructor takes a `BaseWrapper &`. lvalue-references can't bind to temporaries, so the compiler doesn't even take that constructor into consideration. It's like doing this: `int& i = int()`. That reference can never bind to a temporary `int`. On the other hand, rvalue-references allow exactly this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just to sum-up: Adding the private copy constructor will cause the deletion of the move constructor, and all temporaries will be handled by the `Base &` constructor. The private copy constructor should not be needed (bug in `g++ 4.7.2`), and leaving it out will let the compiler use the default move constructor. Due to bug in `g++ 4.7.2`, the lack of the private copy constructor or explicit move constructor makes the compiler erroneously complain about a missing copy constructor.